# Laravel: How to save into two tables , but, the id of the first will be saved into the second as foreign id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables in laravel, the student and parent, the idea is upon creating a student account, the parent account is auto-generated. However, there are chances, a parent can have two children or more in a school. zo, before saving into the database, it should query the parent table to see if the parent exists, if it exists, fetch the id and save it into the student table,  BUT, if the parent does not exist, save the parent into the parent table, thereafter fetch the parent id and save into student table......

sadly, the parent ID is always zero in student id

so far,

```
$parentt = Parentt::where('phone', '=', $request->parentMobileNumber)->first();
 if ($parentt === '') {
            $parenttInstance = new Parentt();
            $parenttInstance->name = $request->parentName;
            $parenttInstance->phone = $request->parentMobileNumber;
            $parenttInstance->password = bcrypt($request->password);
            $parenttInstance->save();

            $parentID = $parenttInstance->id;
        }else {
            $parentID = $parentt->pluck('id');
        }
        }
        $data = array(
            'first_name' => $request->firstName,
            'surname' => $request->lastName,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'gender' => $request->gender,
            'parent_id' =>   $parentID
           'password' =>  Hash::make($request->firstName)


        );
        Student::create($data);
            return back()->with('success', 'Student successfully added.');
```

Comment: try by using  `$parentt->id;` instead of `$parentt->pluck('id');` also better way to use relationships see this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pluck`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_pluck) returns [`Enumerable`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Enumerable.html), you need the actual value, try:

```
$parentID = $parentt->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the pluck() method when there are a collection of objects but in your case, the query returns one object, hence you can directly call the id as @Script47 mentioned.

**$parentID = $parentt->id;**

Comment: Honest question, what value does this answer bring?